# Expandable DIV height to fit internal content - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css-float, expand

## Update

Solved this, it was the inner most div needing to have auto height, as it had a fixed height that I'd completely overlooked

---

I have - like many others I have searched and found - tried to make an expandable DIV that expands based on the length of it's contents. Mine is a little different from those I have seen so far, as I have variables coming from external Controllers to display, but aside from this what I am trying to achieve is the same.
I have created a DIV that contains an image that I repeat-y in the background, however the internal content DIV doesn't want to expand.
I will post my code for some clarity -

```
<div id="feedback_question" class="span-14">
<div id="title_bar">
    <img id="brand_image" src="<?php echo img_path() . $title_row[0]->filename;?>">
    <div id="brand_text">
        <div id="brand_title"><?php echo $title_row[0]->name;?></div>
        <div id="brand_description"><?php echo $title_row[0]->description;?></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="background_stretch">
    <div id="question_background">
        <div id="question_tabs" class="span-14">
            <ul id="tab_list">
                <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $maxQuestions; $i++) { ?>
                <li class="tab" id="tab_<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    Q<?php echo $i; ?>
                </li>
                <?php }; ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="question_body">
            <!--Load question template here -->
            <?php echo $questions?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_section">
        <div id="bottom_button_holder">
            <div id="next_button"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
</div>
<div id="background_bottom">
    <a id="invite_button" href="#"><img src="<?php echo img_path(); ?>feedback/question/invite_button.png"/></a>
</div>
```

---

And here is my CSS -

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.video_multi, .video_multi, .image_multi, .image_multi,  .text_multi, .text_multi {
    display: none;
}

#feedback_question {
     background: transparent url('<?php echo img_path(); ?>feedback/question/question_bg.png') no-repeat scroll;
     height: auto;
}

#title_bar {
    height: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #EBDDE2;
    background: white;
    width: 501px;
    margin-top: 41px;
    margin-left: 8.5px;
}

#brand_image {
    height: 120px;
    width: 170px;
    border: 2.5px solid #EBDDE2;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
}

#brand_text {
    float: right;
    width: 283px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#brand_title {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #4365c6;
}

#brand_description {
    width: 280px;
}

#question_tabs {
     background: transparent url('<?php echo img_path(); ?>feedback/question/tab_bar.png') no-repeat scroll;
     height: 40px;
     padding-top: 22px;
}


#question_background {
     border-left: 1px solid #057eb5;
     border-right: 1px solid #057eb5;
     border-top: 1px solid #057eb5;
     height: 335px;
     width: 501px;
     margin-bottom: -12px;
     overflow: hidden;

}

#tab_list {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.tab {
    background: transparent url('<?php echo img_path(); ?>feedback/question/question_tab_sprite.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
    height: 54px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-right: -3px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    width: 29px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tab_hover{
    background-position: 0px -32px;
}

.tab_selected {
    background-position: 0px -64px;
    color: #0881ba;
}


#bottom_button_holder {
    background: transparent url('<?php echo img_path(); ?>feedback/question/question_button_bg.png') no-repeat scroll;
    height: 47px;
    width: 503px;
    display: block;

}

#next_button {
    background: transparent url('<?php echo img_path(); ?>feedback/question/next_button.png') no-repeat scroll;
    height: 33px;
    width: 98px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 375px;
    top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.question_body {
    height: 270px;
    width: 500px;
}

.question_image_holder {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 100px;
}

.question_answer_box {
    width: 350px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

.answer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 45px;
}

.question {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.answer_text {
    width: 100px;
}

.answer_list_item {
    list-style: none;
}

#background_stretch {
    background: transparent url('<?php echo img_path(); ?>feedback/question/question_bg_repeat.png') repeat-y scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    height:auto;
    padding-left: 8.5px;
}

#background_bottom {
    background: transparent url('<?php echo img_path(); ?>feedback/question/question_bg_bottom.png') no-repeat scroll;
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 520px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;

}

#bottom_section {
    position: relative;
    
}

#invite_button {
    background: transparent url('<?php echo img_path(); ?>feedback/question/invite_button.png') no-repeat scroll;
    display: block;
    height: 52px;
    width: 512px;
    position: relative;

}
```

---

Anyway, as you should be able to see, it is my background_stretch and question_background div's that stretches with the content, this all works well and if I change the height of question_background everything moves as it should.
However, it's getting question_background to adjust to it's internal contents height that is the problem for me.

I have tried various versions of clear:both and floating different boxes, all to no avail...have I overcomplicated it?

What am I doing wrong? How do I achieve this?

Appreciate any help I receive.

Comment: If you can convert this to a static example on a site like jsfiddle.net then we can get back to you with specific fixes.

Answer (score 16):

To make element "extendable" instead of `height: auto;` you should use [`overflow: auto;`](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)(when you change [`float`](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php)). But when you won't touch height it will automaticlly fit - as @kokos said. BTW: Which Div you want to make extendable? (If i guessed right you want to make div with `feedback_question` class)

Useful hint: Add your code to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: thats an empty fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

`#question_background` has a height, if it has a fixed height it will never change no matter how long the content inside it.

Also, next time you are posting such an extensive amount of code please use [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so we can test easier.

Comment: Sorry for the extensive code.
I know that question_background has a fixed height, I just have it at that height but I have tried various alternatives, auto, just give me no height at all...

Comment: When I put your example in jsFiddle (btw, next time also strip out the php) and remove the `height:335px;` it works fine.

Comment: How are you able to get it working without any images? 

I've tried everything with this, taken the height out, put it in, made it auto, nothing is having an effect